# Regular expressions to match several characters Editpad

Tags: html, regex, wordpress, editpad

I have a wordpress export with older posts which are going to be imported into a different installation. But I have an issue where there is a part of the content that needs to be converted into a different type of content in the other installation.

The original code is like this:

```html
<a href="000d3c4c.mp3">000d3c4c</a>]]></content:encoded>
```

And I need to make it into this

```html
     </content:encoded><wp:postmeta>
  <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[mkd_post_audio_link_meta]]></wp:meta_key>
  <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[000d2aa8.mp3]]></wp:meta_value>
 </wp:postmeta>
```

I'm using EditPad Pro to search through the file, and to prevent me from using several hours doing this change manually, I tant to use the extensive search and replace feature in EditPad, but I have some issues trying to match this. I want an expression to be like this.

First search and replace will work no matter what because i can change

```html
<a href="000
```

into

```html
</content:encoded>
<wp:postmeta>
<wp:meta_key>
<![CDATA[mkd_post_audio_link_meta]]></wp:meta_key><wp:meta_value>><![CDATA[000d2aa8.mp3]]></wp:meta_value>
 </wp:postmeta>
```

But I struggle with the next part.
How can I change everything after .mp3 to this

```html
]]></wp:meta_value>
  </wp:postmeta>
```

To make it brief. I want to replace all occurences of

```html
">000d3c4c</a>]]></content:encoded>
```

with

```html
]]></wp:meta_value>
  </wp:postmeta>
```

The **000d3c4c** are different for each occurence of the mp3 link.

Comment: I must be getting old, because I do not see the relationship between what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match this

```
<a[^>]*>([^<]+)
```

and replace by this

```
</content:encoded>
<wp:postmeta>
<wp:meta_key><![CDATA[mkd_post_audio_link_meta]]></wp:meta_key>
<wp:meta_value><![CDATA[$1.mp3]]></wp:meta_value>
</wp:postmeta>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Got almost the same response elsewhere.